# connect to the WiFi network

Tags: xamarin.android

How to programmatically connect to the Wi-Fi network؟
I also want a confirmation message. For the process of communication or non-contact

code not work

```
coneectwifi.Click += delegate
            {
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
                string ssd = "name";
                string key = "pass";

                WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                wifiConfig.Ssid = String.Format("\"%s\"", ssd);
                wifiConfig.PreSharedKey = String.Format("\"%s\"", key);

                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
                //remember id
                int netId = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);
                wifiManager.Disconnect();
                wifiManager.EnableNetwork(netId, true);
                wifiManager.Reconnect();


            };
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is there any error message given?

Comment: I don't see any problem, but nothing happens

Comment: And what have you tried to spot the problem?

Comment: hi nico haase. No result for the code What is the problem with the code? That causes no currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Below Android 9 this code works:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context
                              .GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
                    if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
                        wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(true);
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfig.HiddenSSID = true;
                    wifiConfig.AllowedKeyManagement.Set((int)KeyManagementType.WpaEap);


                   wifiConfig.AllowedKeyManagement.Set((int)KeyManagementType.WpaPsk);
                    wifiConfig.Ssid = $"\"{ssid}\"";
                    wifiConfig.PreSharedKey = $"\"{password}\"";
                    int netId1 = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);
                    wifiManager.RemoveNetwork(netId1);
                    var net_id = wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.NetworkId;
                    wifiManager.DisableNetwork(net_id);
                    int netId = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);
                    wifiManager.Disconnect();
                    bool state = wifiManager.EnableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifiManager.Reconnect();
                    return state;
```

If you want to connect to wifi in android 9 or 10 please ping here.